# How to insert a banner next to the facebook vertical share button

Tags: javascript, css, facebook, html

In aim of using all free space on my page, I need your help to relocating add banner which is under the FB share button I would like it to be right next to it (share, thin banner in right). As I guess it should be solvable by CSS, I'm not good with. Thank you.

I want to get this:
[share] >[banner]

Instead of:

[share]

[banner]

http://pretesti.ge/testtesttest/   my page link

Comment: Can you please provide more and more specific information. What looks your HTML and CSS like.

Comment: i just did add the page im talking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from what I can see, the banner is on top and the share is on the bottom. To make them in the same line, you can use CSS. I visited your website and looked at the code. Before we can start rearranging, there is a `<p></p>` in you code between the banner and the share button. That needs to be deleted. Then your html code should look similar to this:

```
<div class="share-banner">
<div>Facebook stuff goes here</div>
<img alt="banner" src="http://pretesti.ge/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/baner560x60.png">
</div>
```

Now, you need to add some CSS:

```
.share-banner {
display: table; 
}

.share-banner img {
display: table;
float: left:
}

.fb_iframe_widget {
display: table;
float: left;
}
```